# Solution of $x\,dy+y\,dx=du$ when $x$ and $y$ are independent variables

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Wouldn't the answer to $\int x\,dy + \int y\,dx = \int du$ be $xy + xy = u$
which is $$2xy = u+C$$

But my textbook says the answer is $$xy=u+C$$ since $$d(xy)=x\,dy+y\,dx$$
My question is, Isn't this only applicable when $y$ and $x$ are both functions of $x$. Here $x$ and $y$ are both independent since a third variable $u$ is present.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Comparing

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 u & = & u(x,y)\\
du & = & u_x dx + u_y dy\\
du & = & y dx+x dy
\end{array}
\right.
$$

we have $\{u_x = y,\ \ u_y = x \} \Rightarrow \{u_{xy} = u_{yx} = 0\}$

then there exists $u(x,y) = \int u_x dx + \phi_1(y),\ \ u(x,y) = \int u_y dy + \phi_2(x)$

or

$\{u(x,y) = yx+\phi_1(y) = xy+\phi_2(x)\}\Rightarrow u(x,y)=x y + C_0$

Answer (score 1):

When you write $\int x\,dy + \int y\,dx$, these integrals have two different meanings: one integrates with respect to $y$, the other with respect to $x$. So you cannot just put those integrals on each term.

If the problem points out that $x,y$ are independent variables, then $u = u(x,y)$. You have then
$$du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\,dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\,dy = y\,dx + x\,dy.$$
This means $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = y, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = x$, so $u = u(x,y) = xy+C, C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can't I do that. Integrating with respect to different variables

Comment: But didn't we consider x and y as independent variables, i.e, with respect to x, y is constant and vice versa

Comment: @Isham according to your definition $x = g(y)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968244/are-independent-variables-really-independent?s=1|76.9995  See this

Comment: @Allen, I edited the question, I hope it is more clear. As regards your first comment: if two 1-forms are the same, that does not mean their integrals with respect to different variables are the same. So if you apply different integral operators to two equal 1-forms, you are not going to get two equal things.

Comment: What would happen if there were only $\int{xdy}$

Answer (score 0):

A few things

1) I think you may be confused because of experience with double integration.  In double integration, when you integrate with respect to $dy$ you leave $x$'s alone, and when you integrate with respect to $dx$ you leave $y$s alone.  However, here, this isn't a double integral, so that's not what you are doing.  Unfortunately, it is often difficult to tell what people are asking for.

2) So, because this is a single integral, and the things being integrated are total differentials (i.e., not partial differentials), then it is just a basic "reverse differentiation".  When dealing with total differentials, it really doesn't make a lot of difference whether x and y are independent, or if x is actually a function of y, etc.  A lot of people may tell you that it is important, but this is more about *proving* the truth, not doing the math.

3) Since we are dealing with integration as the reverse of differentiation, you cannot integrate $\int x\,dy$ directly, since there is no formula whose differential is $x\,dy$.  However, there is a formula whose differential is $x\,dy + y\,dx$, and that is $xy$.  Therefore, $\int x\,dy + y\,dx = xy$ and $\int du = u$.

Comment: Isham - What difference would it make if y and x were independent of each other to the solution, or if they were each dependent on some third variable?